# How to generate PhpSpreadsheet file without read-only attribute?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am generating an excel .xlsx file using PhpSpreadsheet which can be downloaded with the click of a button.

I am using the following code for headers:

```
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="template - ' . date("dmYHis") . '.xlsx"');
$writer->save('php://output');
die;
```

After downloading the excel, the user then changes some values in it and reuploads it in a form for later processing.

What my problem is: After downloading the excel, **the file is read-only**, and the user cannot modify and save changes in the same file and has to save-as another file and then upload that new file. I want to save the user's extra step.

How can I generate a PhpSpreadsheet without the **read-only** file attribute so that the user is able to modify and save changes in that same file?

Thank you.

Comment: The file will create with badge "is from internet are you sure is safe?", just press confirm to edit for continue and save in the same file

Comment: You are right Simone. I was opening the file while downloading and Firefox was saving it in Local>Temp folder. I guess the files saved in Temp folder are automatically made read-only? I did not know this.
When I save the file and then open it, there is no read-only tag and I can save the modified changes in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

I was opening the file while downloading and Firefox was saving it in Local>Temp folder.

Excel Files saved in Temp folder are automatically made read-only.

When I save the file and then open it from Downloads folder, there is no read-only tag and I can save the modified changes in the same file.